# Allow only one character after decimal in a string?

Tags: php

I got a **string value in number**, like **2345.567**, I want to keep only one character after the decimal. I dont want to use any Number function, I just want to remove any number of character after the period (dot)?

Comment: Why don't you want to use a number function like `round()`?

Comment: @PhpMyCoder - if we use round() for a string and if string contains other than number then it will be taken as 0

Comment: @Vamsi But shouldn't you expect a number? You can't round a sentence. Look at `is_numeric()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
$str =  "2345.567";
$ip = explode('.',$str);
echo $ip[0].".".substr($ip[1],0,1)
?>
```

after edit:

```
<?php
// case:  if there is no decimal place
echo $ip[0]."".($ip[1]?".".substr($ip[1],0,1):'');
?>
```

Comment: There are PHP functions designed to do exactly what the OP wants.

Comment: okey this is what I look for.. I more thing.. if there is no decimal place I want it as the same. No need of period(dot) after the number?

Comment: thank you very much... quick!!!.  thanks all who responded. thank you @vascowhite

Answer (score 4):

If you are worried about the input being not a number, you should validate it first:

```
function round_number($number, $precision = 1) {
    if(!is_numeric($number)) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException("round_number() expects a numeric type, instead received '".gettype($number)."'");
    }

    return round($number, $precision);
}
```

Reference:

- [`round($number, $precision)`](http://php.net/round)
- [`is_numeric($var)`](http://php.net/is_numeric)

Answer (score 3):

```
$number =  2345.567; 

$new_numb = number_format($number,1);
```

$new_numb will be treated as string

Answer (score 1):

Formatted string output can be done with [number_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) or with the [printf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php) family of functions.

```
print number_format((float)$string, 1);
printf("%.1f", $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the input is guaranteed to be well-formed...

`substr($numberString, 0, strpos(".", $numberString) + 2);`

Comment: Gotta love anonymous down votes for code that does exactly what was asked for... For the record, no I don't think this is a good idea, but it does remove digits from a string without using numeric functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as follows

```
$string = "234567.2345";
if(!is_numeric($string)) {
   $output = $string;
}
else{
   $output = round($string,1);
}
```

output will be

```
234567.2
```

if string is given as 234

```
output will be 234.o
```

if string is given other than number "asdf"

```
output will be asdf
```